# Forcing order of excecution with Specs2 Acceptance Style Testing

Tags: scala, specs2

I'm trying to get my tests to execute sequentially with Specs2 acceptance style testing, but I'm not having any luck.

```
  override def is = {     
    "Template Project REST Specification" ^
      p ^
      "The server should" ^
      "Respond with greeting on root path" ! serverRunning ^
      p ^
      "For CLIENT json objects" ^
      "Return an empty list if there are no entities" ! getEmptyClientList ^
      "Create a new entity" ! createClient ^
      "Return a non-empty list if there some entities" ! getNonEmptyClientList ^
      "Read existing" ! todo ^
      "Update existing" ! todo ^
      "Delete existing" ! todo ^
      "Handle missing fields" ! todo ^
      "Handle invalid fields" ! todo ^
      "Return error if the entity does not exist" ! todo ^
      end
  }
```

When running the tests, the `createClient` test keeps creating a new client element before the `getEmptyClientList` test gets a chance to execute.

If I add a whole heap of `getEmptyClientList` tests before the `createClient` test, then all but the last one will execute before the call to `createClient`. But `createClient` will always beat the last `getEmptyClientList` call, which results in it failing.

How do I force it to execute sequentially? With Specs2 unit testing style, I just added the `sequential` keyword before the tests and all would be well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In acceptance specifications, the `sequential` argument can be added at the beginning of the specification like this:

```
def is = sequential ^
  "Template Project REST Specification" ^
   p ^
   "The server should" ^
   "Respond with greeting on root path" ! serverRunning ^
   p ^
   "For CLIENT json objects" ^
   "Return an empty list if there are no entities" ! getEmptyClientList ^
   "Create a new entity" ! createClient ^
   "Return a non-empty list if there some entities" ! getNonEmptyClientList ^
   "Read existing" ! todo ^
   "Update existing" ! todo ^
   "Delete existing" ! todo ^
   "Handle missing fields" ! todo ^
   "Handle invalid fields" ! todo ^
   "Return error if the entity does not exist" ! todo ^
   end
```

Note that you don't need to `override` the `is` method and you also don't need curly braces.

Comment: Thanks Eric, that worked. Regarding the comment on 'override': The compiler complains that method 'is' in 'org.specs2.specification.Fragments' needs an override modifier if I leave out the 'override'.

Comment: Are you sure you are using `org.specs2.Specification` (which has an abstract `is` method) and not `org.specs2.mutable.Specification` (which has a concrete `is` method)?